# Ubuntu 22.04. The problem with additional applications after installation

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, vlc, netbeans

[image]
Hello everybody! I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I worked on Ubuntu 16.04. I had one problem with those applications that are not in the official Ubuntu repository and which need to be installed extra, including Google Chrome, Apache Net Beans, VLC Media Player. They are successful, started successfully, but the windows remain invisible. That's the way it is shown on the screenshot.

That is, the app is running, but I can't make the application window visible. I have this problem with all the applications I installed extra after Ubuntu installation 22.04. Those applications that have been in the official repository function normally, the windows are visible, but with these applications such a problem.

How can this be fixed? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: VLC is in the official repository.

Comment: Log out, switch to "Xorg on Ubuntu" and log in again. I don't have these problems, so how did you install those "deb" files?

Comment: I tried to do this, switch to "Xorg on Ubuntu", but it doesn't help.

Comment: I installed these applications through the Ubuntu software manager.